# Error when I try running this SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running this bit of code but  I get this error for each line.

---

Error starting at line : 140 in command -
INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0321', 'SA3 4JK', '74 ',TO_DATE ('11-10-2016', '09:12:21'))
Error at Command Line : 140 Column : 39
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DELIVERY_ADDRESS": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

---

```
 CREATE TABLE Delivery_tbl (

 Delivery_ID varchar2(5),
  Delivery_Postcode varchar2 (10),
  Delivery_HouseNo varchar2 (10),
  Delivery_date_time date ,

   PRIMARY KEY (Delivery_ID)
   );
 INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo,   Delivery_date_time) VALUES ('D0789', 'GL3 2QU', '8', TO_DATE('20-02-2016', '13:12:35'));
 INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0456' 'GL3 2HO', '21', TO_DATE ('28-02-2016', '16:51:32'));
 INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0123', 'BH8 6UG', '420', TO_DATE ('28-11-2016', '11:15:02'));
 INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0987', 'HI8 9BH', '54', TO_DATE ('20-04-2016', '12:05:54'));
 INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0654', 'DU7 3DF', '63', TO_DATE ('22-05-2016', '10:45:12'));
  INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0321', 'SA3 4JK', '74 ',TO_DATE ('11-10-2016', '09:12:21'));
   INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0741', 'BH8 8GH', ' 14 ', TO_DATE ('22-03-2016', '15:56:01'));
   INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0851', 'BH8 8AS', '56', TO_DATE ('15-07-2016', '18:02:45'));
INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0963', 'GL51 2AS', '105', TO_DATE ('08-01-2016', '17:14:41'));
INSERT INTO Delivery_tbl (Deliver_ID, Delivery_Address, Delivery_HouseNo, Delivery_date_time) VALUES ( 'D0753', 'GH5 3TU', '12', TO_DATE ('16-09-2016', '14:15:52'));
```

Comment: After you add the column Delivery_Address to your table and run the statements again, you will get a new error, because in your table the first column is Delivery_ID but in the INSERT statement you have Deliver_ID. Contrary to popular opinion, computers are incredibly dumb, they can't read your mind. You have to be 100% precise when you write code or else nothing will work.

Comment: Sorry for late reply,thank you I have Corrected those errors but when I run it now i get an error of Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"

Comment: Google "oracle to_date" and learn the proper syntax, look at a couple of examples and you will see very quickly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: ok, think i found the problem. Is it because the format is the wrong way round should be yyyy/mm/dd and i have put dd-mm-yyyy ?

Comment: No, you can put those in any order you like. But the `to_date()` function itself should be something like `to_date(2005-03-20 15:33:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`. The first string contains both the date AND the time, and the second shows exactly how the string must be interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

You created table without `delivery_address` column, but you are trying to insert into that very column. Add the column to your create table statement first.

Comment: I have Corrected those errors but when I run it now i get an error of Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized 01821. 00000 - "date format not recognized"

Comment: Look up to_date function documentation. You are supplying incorrect parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no column having the name delivery_address in your table,

CREATE or replace TABLE Delivery_tbl (

Delivery_ID varchar2(5),
  Delivery_address varchar2 (10),
  Delivery_HouseNo varchar2 (10),
  Delivery_date_time date ,

PRIMARY KEY (Delivery_ID)
   );